# unable to copy ##vso command in an existing powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline having multiple stages in it. My requirement is to create a PowerShell script in one of the stages and publish it as an artifact, that will be consumed by another step in a later stage. Following is what my template look like; where the PowerShell script will be created and then published (I had to take out most part of it to make it look simpler)

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    $powershell = @"
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('namespace', "abc");
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=namespace]abc";
    "@;
    Set-Content -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/variables.ps1" -Value $powershell;

- ${{ each parameter in parameters.k8Variables.variables }}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host ${{ parameter.Key }}
      Write-Host ${{ parameter.Value }}
      $content = "Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ parameter.Key }}]${{ parameter.Value }}";"
      Add-Content -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/variables.ps1" -Value $content
```

The issue is that when the `variables.ps1` file is created, its content looks like below:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('namespace', "abc");
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=namespace]abc";
Write-Host 
Write-Host
```

The second PowerShell task doesn't add any thing to the file only `Write-Host`, this might be due to the `##vso` as when I use normal string in it the content gets published and looks fine but `##vso` does not even seem to appear on the script. Is there a way I can add the last two lines as expected with the `##vso..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're trying to use *embedded* `"` chars. inside an `"..."` string *without escaping them***.

In this case, because no string interpolation *by PowerShell* is required, the simplest solution is to use `'...'` for the outer quoting, which allows you to use embedded `"` as-is (generally, to embed `"` inside `"..."`, use `` `" ``).

```
# Note the outer '...' quoting.
$content = 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ parameter.Key }}]${{ parameter.Value }}";'
```

See also: the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$content = "Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable ...`

PowerShell parses this as follows:

- Double-quoted string literal `"Write-Host "`
- followed by a `#` char., causing PowerShell to consider the remainder of the line to be a *comment*

Thus, you'll end up with verbatim `Write-Host`  in `$content`